# Firebase Realtime DB How to insert item into all exist array with PHP

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to insert "empEmail" into all existing arrays (I have 100 rows) in firebase realtime DB

> Like This

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific, built-in operation to do this. You will need to:

1. Read the data at `/docEmpProfile/$id`.
2. Loop over the child nodes in the result.
3. Write the new property to each child node.

As a separate note: using sequential, numeric indexes as keys is an antipattern in the Firebase Realtime Database. To learn why and the more idiomatic way to structure the data, see [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.blog/posts/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase).